# Rewrite Custom Fields url

Tags: custom-field, url-rewriting

I use custom fields named 'url' to add another website url (like `http://www.youtube.com`), I want to rewrite the 'url' as `http://www.mysite.com/go/123`.

I tried all rewrite plugins, no one could do this.

Can I set post id as 123? Or can I set a random number as it?

Comment: Are you trying to proxy Youtube via a URL on your site?

Comment: Do you mean redirect to external site? Rewrite is usually for manipulating URLs to resources on your site.

Comment: I add more info.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial ([Build a Short URL Service with WordPress Custom Post Types](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-short-url-service-with-wordpress-custom-post-types/))
that show how to create this kind of redirection

or you can use a plugin that does that for you [GoTo Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/goto-redirect/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't say clearly, just add more info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, I want to auto rewrite link when I add it in custom fields named "url".

For example:

I named a "url" in custom fields add www.yahoo.com as value, I use `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', true); ?>` to get it, I don't want to show the link www.yahoo.com, I want to rewrite it as www.mysite.com/29382 with random number automatically generated.